# How to find dispersion relation for 1 d topological insulator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

Is it correct to write the dispersion relation for following Hamiltonian where $\sigma_{x}$ act in spin space and $\tau_{x}$ acts in pseudo spin particle hole spin
$H_{BdG} (k)=(\xi_{k}+B\sigma_{x}+u sin(k)\sigma_{y})\tau_{z}+\Delta\sigma_{y}\tau_{y}$

$E(k)=\sqrt[2]{\xi_{k} ^{2}+B^{2} +(u Sin(k))^{2}+\Delta^{2}}$
because pauli matrices for spin and pseudo spin are acting in orthogonal spaces, but when I am trying to solve the $4\times4$ matrix of above hamiltonian to find eigenvalue I can't get to the above dispersion relation what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your BdG Hamiltonian is wrong.

Comment: @EverettYou can you specify the mistake ?

Comment: @Everettyou I have checked it again and I think it is right.

Comment: Your Hamiltonian can not give the $E(k)$ you want, but the following Hamiltonian can $H_\text{BdG}=\xi_k\sigma_z+B\sigma_x+u\sin k\sigma_y\tau_z+\Delta\sigma_y\tau_y$